# Useless render issues in Trident-based browsers - what is causing this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote the code for a website and tested it only in Chrome. It displays as I want it to. But, Trident-based browsers like Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge seem to render the website differently. Am I using unsupported tags? Is there some incorrect CSS? I have no idea why this would not display as expected in multiple browsers. A brief description of what the render issues are- it renders the whole site with very enlarged elements, as if the user had zoomed in by something like 500%

The original website link is also down below for testing purposes. I have also attached screenshots of what this looks like from my point of view. After double checking *ALL* of the CSS, I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong. So, if there genuinely is nothing wrong, what can I do to resolve the horrid scaling issue?

- [Here is the website link.](http://sharansembhiartiste.co.uk/XMAS_REVEAL_TEST/index.html)
- [Screenshots in Chrome, Edge and IE11.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHsc2.jpg)

(and, yes, the backgrounds may be different on each screenshot as the background dynamically changes with CSS animations)

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css` at Question?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Well, I'm not sure how. The problem does not get re-produced correctly when I just include snippets of the code, as it requires the ability to load the buttons/elements correctly from the server where the site is hosted.

Comment: I would start whittling down the HTML/CSS/JavaScript until you're no longer seeing the issue, then add back in the last thing you took out. This question won't help anyone once that link goes stale. At the *very least* remove the audio.